# count repeated records in a table of a specific column

Tags: sql

i am a newbie to SQL Server, I need to get the value of how many times you repeat a value in a column, and group it by the number of times repeated, by location.

i mean:

```
Table ACTIVITY
id     orderID      Location       date   

x      order11       NewYork      xxxx     
x      order22       Miami        xxxx    
x      order11       LA           xxxx
x      order33       NewYork      xxxx   
x      order11       NewYork      xxxx
x      order22       Miami        xxxx
x      order22       NewYork      xxxx
x      order44       Miami        xxxx
```

i have this:

```
Select [orderID], count(1) as CountOrder from [MobileService].[ACTIVITY]
Group by [orderID]
Order BY CountOrder Desc
```

and returns me:

```
orderID       CountOrder    

order11       3
order22       3
order33       1
order44       1
```

ok, Good, but, i want to filter by Location

```
Select [NewsItemTitle], count(1) as xx from [MobileServiceExtra].[ACTIVITY]
Group by [NewsItemTitle]
Order BY xx Desc
WHERE [Location] = 'NewYork'
```

and returns me Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

So, i want to get the following result if I filter by NewYork

```
orderID      CountOrder       

order11      2         
order22      1
order33      1
```

How I can fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you were close you just had the order wrong:

```
Select [NewsItemTitle], count(1) as xx from [MobileServiceExtra].[ACTIVITY]
WHERE [Location] = 'NewYork'
Group by [NewsItemTitle]
Order BY xx Desc
```

Comment: Thnks!, very close, jeje.